# Error handling for write() and close() in c

Tags: c, file, error-handling

I am trying to catch errors and print them in a specific way, and managed to do it for open() and read() but can't for write() and close().

```
    for(size_t i = 0;buff[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        j = write(STDOUT_FILENO, &buff[i], 1);
        if(j == -1)
        {
            write(STDOUT_FILENO, "tail: error writing 'standard output': ", strlen("tail: error writing 'standard output': "));
            write(STDOUT_FILENO, strerror(errno), strlen(strerror(errno)));
            write(STDOUT_FILENO, "\n", strlen("\n"));
            return errno;
        }

    }
```

I have saved some input from stdin in buff and am trying to print the error "No space left on device". I don't know how to test it on my own on Linux, since I don't know what input would cause this error.

```
int j=close(fd);
    if(j == -1)
    {
        write(STDOUT_FILENO, "tail: error reading '", strlen("tail: error reading '"));
        write(STDOUT_FILENO, path, strlen(path));
        write(STDOUT_FILENO, "': ", strlen("': "));
        write(STDOUT_FILENO, strerror(errno), strlen(strerror(errno)));
        write(STDOUT_FILENO, "\n", strlen("\n"));
        return errno;
    }
```

And for close() its the same. I am opening a file to read from and then closing it. I can't really test it because the error would probably be first caught in open() but I need to output "Input/output error". Don't know how to test this either.

I know they both don't work cause there's a grader where I submit my work and it runs a bunch of tests and it fails the 2 for error handling of write() and close().

I managed to try open() with a nonexisting file and read() with a directory /tmp/. It does say to test write with > /dev/full but for me it doesn't seem to do anything. Are there any other methods to test it?

Comment: Not actually what you are asking but perhaps even more important is that your code is only returning the error for the last function call. To be entirely correct it should check every function call as an earlier one could fail but the last one succeed (e.g. if the write size is different). Maybe that's even the reason why it's failing with the grader.

Comment: For your actual problem - you need to save `errno` immediately after the call you want to check. Otherwise it can change with any following call. So the act of printing the error can change the `errno`.

Comment: @kaylum Well I actually set errno = 0 at the beginning of the function so it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: It is a problem. If `j=close(fd);` gets an error the `errno` may be overwritten as soon as you call the first `write` in the error handling. So by the time `strerror(errno)` is called the `errno` is not the value for the `close` call. Same for `return errno`.

Comment: So to fix this I need to save it in a variable?

Comment: Yeah, that's what "you need to save errno" means.

Comment: Just tried it, still doesn't work.

Comment: It is possible that they're correct and another part of the program is doing sth wrong, since the grader isn't the best, but as far as I've tested everything else seems to work properly.

Comment: Well then you need to provide more info than "doesn't work". What exactly is the being tested? Please provide complete code as a [mre]. Maybe the tester requires different output than you are giving. That's not something we can help with without knowing the full details of the requirements and the testing.

Comment: Well the grader just says: "Check error handling of write. You should handle write errors." and the same for close(). I have no idea what the exact test are that it runs. Well whatever was in the problem's requirements especially the outputs should be 1:1 i've copied them directly from there and checked them a few times.

Comment: We can't help with that - speak to your teaching staff. One possibility is that you are only checking for `-1`. But write can return a "success" but less than the requested number of bytes. Perhaps the tester requires that to be flagged as an error - again, not something we can help with.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your help!